# IEEE 754: Underflow: is inexact flag required to be raised?

Tags: exception, floating-point, language-lawyer, ieee-754, underflow

IEEE 754-2008, 7.5 Underflow:

> The underflow exception shall be signaled ...
>
> ... the underflow flag shall be raised and the inexact (see 7.6) exception shall be signaled.

Here we see that:

- the underflow flag is required to be raised AND the underflow exception is required to be signaled
- the inexact flag is required to be signaled

Simple question: is inexact flag required to be raised?

Reason of the question: as I understand: *flag is raised*  != *exception is signaled*. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

7.6 Inexact (emphaisis added):

> When all of these exceptions are handled by default, the *inexact flag is always raised* when either the overflow or *underflow flag is raised*.